# How to place a box around a piece of text in Org mode

Tags: org-mode

Whenever, I export my org-documents to html, I notice that by default, 
my source code snippets get placed inside a box, which is good. I don't see the same behavior when I export my org documents as pdfs via latex.

So given a paragraph of text, not necessarily source code, how would I place a box around the text.

So I would imagine the solution would look like

```
#+BEGIN_BOX -- how to do this? Any other solution also will do

The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox.
#+BEGIN_SRC python
 print "Hello World"
#+END_SRC 

#+END_BOX
```

Creates a box around the text and source code after exporting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `#+BEGIN_mdframed`, and in my LaTeX export use,

```
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA:  \usepackage{mdframed}
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{mdframed}}
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{mdframed}}
```

Comment: Perfect! I presume your solution will wrap any text wrapped inside a begin end org block with a box right? Also do you know how to customize the color of the framed box?